# React Native - Problem with transparentModal changing height of header and bottom navigation bar on iOS devices with notch or dynamic island

Tags: ios, react-native

Here is a stripped down react native app that demonstrates the problem: https://github.com/divelogs/modal-test

When run on an iOS device with notch or dynamic island, closing the modal (presentation: 'transparentModal') will change the height of the header and bottom navigation bar in landscape mode. This persists until you force close the app. If the device has no notch, it works as expected. Simulator shows this as well as physical devices.

Before opening and closing the modal:
[image]

After opening and closing the modal:
[image]

As I am fairly new to react native, I have no idea where to start here, but I guess this is a bug somewhere in the react native modules?

App.tsx code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const BottomNavigation = ()=> {

  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  return (<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
      tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: '#3fb9f2'},
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#3fb9f2'},
      headerTitle: () => <Text>Header Text</Text>,
      headerTitleAlign: 'center'      
    }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Something" options={{ 
        title: "something",
        headerShown: false, 
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#FFFFFF', 
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
        tabBarLabelStyle: {fontSize: 14}
      }}>
        {(props) => { return <DivesNavigation {...props}/>}}
      </Tab.Screen>       
    </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}

const DivesNavigation = ({navigation}:any) => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  const focusDiveProfile = () => {
    navigation.navigate("MyModalWindow");
  }

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#3fb9f2'
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitle: () => <Text>My header</Text>,
            headerTitleAlign: 'center'           
          }}          
        >
        
        <Stack.Screen name="Demo">
          {(props) => {return <Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => focusDiveProfile()}>
              <Text style={{padding: 30}}>This is to demonstrate a problem with transparentModal on iOS devices 
                with a notch or dynamic island. 
                Click to open modal in LANDSCAPE mode and then close it.
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </Text>}}
        </Stack.Screen>
        
        <Stack.Screen
          name="MyModalWindow"
          component={Modalcontent}
          options={{ presentation: 'transparentModal', headerShown: false }}
        />   

      </Stack.Navigator>   
    </View>
  );
};


const Modalcontent = ({navigation}:any) => {

  const closeModal = () => {
    navigation.pop()
  }

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 30, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}}>
        <Text>This modal needs to be full screen, as it will contain a lot of (interactive) content and I do not want 
          the title or bottom bar to show. Click on close in the next line, and the header and footer will be higher than before, 
          taking up much more space until you force close the app:
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={closeModal}>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Close Modal</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default BottomNavigation
```